# chromium already at latest revision 73 when try apt install

Tags: debian, apt, chrome

im trying to upgrade chromium on debian and it tells me when i run

```
apt install chromium-browser
```

i get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package chromium-browser is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'chromium-browser' has no installation candidate
```

and when i run

```
apt install chromium
```

it says its already at latest, version 73, and i know there's newer versions.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
chromium is already the newest version (73.0.3683.75-1~deb9u1)
```

how do i proceed? im not a sysadmin, so this is new to me.

Comment: @Paul then vote to migrate the question. It is still worth answering there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the package version (73.0.3683.75-1~**deb9**u1) we can see that you are still on Debian 9.

Debian 9 reached it's end of life in January 2020. While the LTS end date is June 2022, [LTS means that it only receives security updates](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/FAQ), no feature updates anymore. And the security updates are not handled by Debian, but by volunteers.

You should upgrade Debian to a newer version (the current version is 11). You will NOT get any new versions of any packages with this version of Debian.